# What is a good book/guide for socket programming in C?

Tags: c++, c, unix, sockets

Could anybody please tell me which is best guide/book/material for socket programming in C?
I am reading beej's guide for network programming but it just gives an overview.
Can you suggest any other books or guides?

Comment: Beej's guide for network programming is more than enough for most simple applications.

Comment: I agree with Kylotan, Beej's guide is pretty good. If that's not good enough then I guess go straight to UNIX Network Programming Volume 1. :)

Comment: I think this topic is also discussed in the APUE book in case you already have access to it :-).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[UNIX Network Programming, Volume 1, Second Edition: Networking APIs: Sockets and XTI](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html).

Then go from there.

Comment: agree. it's something like the Bible. after done, study Highly-concurrent Programming Models. suggest that if on a linux 2.6x study to use epoll, if win/msvc, try competion port. and new AIO. visit Effo NetMsg C/C++ open source project to learn more about epoll, network messaging and Highly-concurrent Programming Models.

Comment: Possibly stupid question: is it worth reading if you plan to program on windows?

Comment: @nikie Yes, IMHO. But, I remember benefiting from the 1995 edition of http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Sockets-Network-Programming-paperback/dp/0768682320/

Comment: @sinan this should certainly apply and work on any modern linux distro right ?

Comment: should I read volume 2 after I have read volume 1 of socket programming? The volume 2 is rather IPC then networking

Answer (score 5):

Start with UNIX Network Programming as [Sinan Ünür said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594949/socket-programming-in-c/1594965#1594965).  Read [TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html) after you have decent grasp on sockets.  Don't skip this since it will increase your knowledge of the various network protocols dramatically.  FWIW, I think that these two books should form the foundation of anyone that even considers doing network programming at the socket layer.

Comment: should I read volume 2 after I have read volume 1 of socket programming? The volume 2 is rather IPC then networking

Comment: UNIX Network Programming vol 2 isn't really that useful for IP-based network programming.  It's useful if you are doing thread-based programming.  I would take a look at Stevens' Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment for more UNIX system programming outside of networking.

Comment: I really appreciate the UNIX system programming, but I am rather interested in creating CGI in c or c++, after comprehending sockets, I cannot find a the same quality book for CGI/web development in c++ (which would follow the socket api knowledge now I have). Do you know any?