# C++ and internet program

Tags: c++, networking

I've been self teaching myself C++ for the last 6 months and I would like to put my little acquired knowledge into a relatively useful program.
I would like to make a program that will ask for an input, (here's the tricky part) search in a list of websites (including other pages in said website) for that input's value and display the results.
Truth is, I don't really know how to get started since I haven't read any guide on c++ and networking, so if you do have a good guide in mind, please share it with me, much appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, the program in itself isn't really what worries me, i'm just looking for a guide that explains how to combine c++ and networking. And I want it to be something like a price comparison program, take an input from the user, search the input in a list of websites, get the result, look for it's value and display the results in an increasing order

Comment: You want to take the input from a list of website or what.Plz Elaborate

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, the program in itself isn't really what worries me, i'm just looking for a guide that explains how to combine c++ and networking.
And I want it to be something like a price comparison program, take an input from the user, search the input in a list of websites, get the result, look for it's value and display the results in an increasing order

Comment: Looking for guide is off-topic here.

Comment: I have apparently pissed off 2 guys and getting flagged for off-topic, I'm not really sure what have I done wrong, if someone were to tell me I would make sure I don't do it again

Comment: Off-topic means your question isn't appropriate for SO and should be closed, that's all, it's nothing personal. Read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Newbie2SO SO is intended for specific questions that can be answered in a precise manner, asking for a tool/library or anything else which is based on opinion is better suited for a discussion forum (even though sometimes opinion based things do sneak through here).

Comment: Sorry about it, will not happen again

Comment: But you can edit and change it What are the different libraries, what we use for xyz, How we do xyz ... not for good, Or opinion based.

Comment: TBH I don't think the question can be salvaged. We'd still want the question to show a reasonable effort - you should have spent enough time searching for an answer on the Internet. And in this case, you'd have a list of viable options. Also missing from this question is the high-level breakdown which shows the problem is understood. In this case, it's worrying that HTML isn't even mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

You may wish to start looking into Networking libraries for c++. keep in mind there are many library and choosing the right one will purely depends on your requirement. Here is the quick list of c++ networking libraries that I've considered in past!

- [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is really good, though the documentation is scarce.
- [C++ Network Library](http://mikhailberis.github.com/cpp-netlib/)
- [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)
- [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)
- [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)
- [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)
- [Apache APR](http://apr.apache.org/)

Also see the post by '[George Stocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker)' at https://stackoverflow.com/a/118968/3685825

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll look into them right now.

Comment: @Ankit Patel Good listing I don't know about POCO have you used it.

Comment: @ali786, "Have I used Poco for networking?" In a commercial product? No. However I have used it with the initial prototype building. A good POCO networking guide at http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Generally We Use Sockets In c++ for Network programming. And Sockets uses following protocol families.

> PF_UNIX    Local communication
>
> PF_INET    Internet (TCP/IP)
>
> PF_NDD The operating system NDD

`PF_INET` contains following protocol.

> TCP
>
> UDP
>
> RDS
>
> IP
>
> Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)

And for Calling an HTTP protocol you need a middle-ware since socket can't communicate directly to the HTTP protocol.

See this question for calling an HTTP URL from c++.

[How do you make a HTTP request with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

And for socket Reference I suggest you to read

dvanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment.
By W. Richard Stevens, Stephen A. Rago

for other references

[What is a good book/guide for socket programming in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594949/what-is-a-good-book-guide-for-socket-programming-in-c)

Comment: Thank you so much man, much appreciated, will keep you updated